# Binance API: APIError(code=-1111): Precision is over the maximum defined for this asset. Python

Tags: python, binance

I have done a program, and works fine with ltcusdt, but gives this error with for example aaveusdt, I don't understand why. Can some one explain me whats the difference between them two (the two pairs have the same number of decimals, and similar price (200-100)) how and what should I change?

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to provide you're code for anyone to figure out anything specific about your error, but basically each pair has it's own precision, Bitcoin which is about $50000, won't take the same decimals as Doge which is about $0.15

With the response you get from the  [GET /api/v3/exchangeInfo](https://binance-docs.github.io/apidocs/spot/en/#exchange-information) endpoint,

```js
{
  "timezone": "UTC",
  "serverTime": 1565246363776,
  "rateLimits": [
    {
      //These are defined in the `ENUM definitions` section under `Rate Limiters (rateLimitType)`.
      //All limits are optional
    }
  ],
  "exchangeFilters": [
    //These are the defined filters in the `Filters` section.
    //All filters are optional.
  ],
  "symbols": [
    {
      "symbol": "ETHBTC",
      "status": "TRADING",
      "baseAsset": "ETH",
      "baseAssetPrecision": 8,
      "quoteAsset": "BTC",
      "quotePrecision": 8,
      "quoteAssetPrecision": 8,
      "orderTypes": [
        "LIMIT",
        "LIMIT_MAKER",
        "MARKET",
        "STOP_LOSS",
        "STOP_LOSS_LIMIT",
        "TAKE_PROFIT",
        "TAKE_PROFIT_LIMIT"
      ],
      "icebergAllowed": true,
      "ocoAllowed": true,
      "isSpotTradingAllowed": true,
      "isMarginTradingAllowed": true,
      "filters": [
        //These are defined in the Filters section.
        //All filters are optional
      ],
      "permissions": [
         "SPOT",
         "MARGIN"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

you can get the precision for each endpoint from the keys

- `baseAssetPrecision`
- `quotePrecision`
- `quoteAssetPrecision`
- `baseCommissionPrecision`
- `quoteCommissionPrecision`

---

Also [CCXT](https://github.com/ccxt/ccxt) is an open source library that takes care of all the precision stuff and auto trims numbers so that they don't exceed the precision limits

There's a list of [examples](https://github.com/ccxt/ccxt/tree/master/examples) in the [repo](https://github.com/ccxt/ccxt) at `ccxt/examples` and this is [the manual](https://docs.ccxt.com/en/latest/index.html)